# Highstock data not showing when setting xAxis min and max

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I'm not able to set the xAxis min and max without screwing with the data. I tried using `plotOptions` and setting `pointStart: Date.UTC(2016, 3, 1)` but doing that screws with the data. The series ends up on the far right and doesn't load properly.

Is it possible to set a min and a max and make the data obey whatever is set? It loads properly when I don't set `min` and `max`. I need it to start in April 2016 and end on April 2018 with a tick every month.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/omaraziz/h5jsk7a3/5/

Here is an almost working version that just needs the xAxis dates and the tick (data is not exactly the same, but the same exact setting of the json:

[image]

The data is coming from a JSON file (data.json):

```
{
   "(1)": [1,2,3,4,5],
   "(2)": [6,7,8,9,0]
   "(3)": [1,4,7,2,0]
}
```

Setting the options:

```
var myChart = function() drawChart() {
     $("#container").highcharts("StockChart", {

            rangeSelector: {
                 enabled: false
            },

            xAxis: {
                 type: 'datetime',
                 tickInterval: (24 * 3600 * 1000) * 30, // every month
                 min: Date.UTC(2016, 3, 1),
                 max: Date.UTC(2018, 3, 4)
            },

           series: processedData, // from the data loaded below

    });

};
```

Loading JSON:

```
processedData = [];

$(function () {
    $getJSON("data.json", function(data) {

        for(let value in data) {

            if(data.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
                processedData.push({
                   name: value,
                   data: data[value],
                })

        }
        myChart(); // after the data has loaded
   });
});
```

Comment: what are your data `x` values? I mean each of your series contains about 11126 value. are they per hour values?

Comment: @pooyan you mean the ones coming from the JSON? They are data which I copied from a big excel file. The format of the data is exactly identical to the json structure I posted here. The range of the data is from 0 to ~800

Comment: Yes, I mean the data that comes from the json file. According to these data, each of your series will contains about 11126 values which you should determine their `x`axis. For example you should know that each of this data are per hours data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Your are recording your data at each hour, I hope your problem would be solved by using these two lines of code:

```
pointStart:Date.UTC(2016, 3, 1),
pointInterval: 3600 * 1000
```

**Here is example:**

```js
var myChart = function drawChart() {

    $("#container").highcharts("StockChart", {

        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: false,
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            ordinal: false,
            min:   Date.UTC(2016, 3, 1),
            max:  Date.UTC(2018, 3, 4)

        },
        plotOptions:{
            series:{
                pointStart:Date.UTC(2016, 3, 1),
                pointInterval: 3600 * 1000
            }
        },

        series: processedData,

    });

};

const processedData = [];

$(function () {
    $.getJSON("https://omaraziz.me/CC-chart/new-activity.json", function (data) {

        for(let value in data) {
            if(data.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
                processedData.push({
                    //pointStart: Date.UTC(2016, 3, 1),
                    name: value,
                    data: data[value],
                })
            }
        }
        myChart();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.src.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome, this is very helpful. Only one thing, how do I make it end at Mar' 2018 instead of Jul' 17?

Comment: I hope `ordinal: false,` will do the trick. Take a look at My answer's edited Code Snippet.

Comment: Quick question, is it possible to stretch the data to fit that range? If it's not possible on two years then maybe one year? Let's say the range is one year (Jul. '17 to Apr. '18).

Comment: It depend on the number of  your data and the `tickInterval` setting.